# Placement of tokens in tikz/petri

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there some easy trick to make `\node[place,tokens=3]{}` place 3 tokens in a row (and not in a triangle)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the file [tikzlibrarypetri.code.tex](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypetri.code.tex) you would find the needed macros. There are commands `\tikz@def@grow@tokens{number of tokens}{number of the token}{x shift}{y shift}` as in Grigorys comment) that can be analyzed and modified.

Here's the modification for `number of tokens`= 3 and `number of the token`= 1, 2, 3 - just place this code in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\tikz@def@grow@tokens{3}{1}{-1}{0}
\tikz@def@grow@tokens{3}{2}{0}{0}
\tikz@def@grow@tokens{3}{3}{1}{0}
\makeatother
```

Sample output of the modified manual Petri-net example:

[image]

Note the three tokens in a row in the middle of the image.

Comment: We could probably do with an explanation of how you came up with that!

Comment: great, thanks! general syntax is something like "\tikz@def@grow@tokens{number of tokens}{number of the token}{x shift}{y shift}", I [guess](http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypetri.code.tex)

Comment: @Joseph: I've just read the file tikzlibrarypetri.code.tex, Grigory put a link in his comment.

Comment: @Joseph: I`ve added some explanation.