# Tikz Petri-Net - How to place a not token on an edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a "not A"-token next to an edge. Is there a build in function in Tikz -> petri for that? I have seen a dot in front of the token to symbolize a negation. (cant find it right now, will try to find it again tomorrow). But the tikz documentation is rather short for the petri library. Are there individual docs for each tikz-library somewhere?

[image: petri-net with store and a type based transition for either A-tokens or not-A-tokens]

And is it possible to control the spacing of the multiple tokens in a store (here named: "source")? I did find a manual way, but that does not feel to be the way one is supposed do it: [Placement of tokens in tikz/petri](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/placement-of-tokens-in-tikz-petri)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,decorations,automata,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,circle,inner sep=0mm,minimum size=6mm,
label distance=0mm,node distance=10mm,thick,>=stealth',auto,
%styles
Store/.style={ellipse,draw=black,thick,minimum height=10mm,minimum width=17mm},
store/.style={ellipse,draw=black,thick,minimum height=6mm,minimum width=9mm},
place/.style={circle,draw=black,thick,},
trans/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick},
edgetoken/.style={above=1mm,circle,fill=black,minimum size=2.5mm}]

\node (source)  [Store, label={left:source}] at (0,0) {}
[children are tokens]
child {node [token] {A}}
child {node [token] {B}}
child {node [token] {C}};

\node (t1)  [trans, right=of source]            {$t_{1}$}
edge [<-] node[edgetoken]{} (source);

\node (A)   [store, right=of t1, label={right:A}] {}
[children are tokens]
child {node [token] {A}}    
edge [<-] node[token,above]{A} (t1);    % token A

\node (not_B)   [store, below=of A, label={right:not A}] {}
[children are tokens]
child {node [token] {B}}
child {node [token] {C}}
edge [<-] node[token,above]{BC} (t1);   % not token A
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you are asking. You show how to replace the `BC` on the `edge` with something different. Yet you seem to be asking how to replace it with something different. Are you asking for a good way to symbolise `not A`? That is not really on-topic but I'd think it is highly dependent on your discipline `\=A` would not mean `not A` to people in my subject (generally), so I'd obviously use something else. But you need to use what your audience will understand.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your advice. You were right, my question was not clear. And negation does depend on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to your second question because I understand that one ;).

I've updated the syntax to use current versions of a couple of libraries as now recommended and minimised it a bit by not loading some libraries not required for your example. Obviously reinstate these in your original document since you presumably need them there.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.geometric,positioning,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    ->,
    circle,
    inner sep=0mm,
    minimum size=6mm,
    label distance=0mm,
    node distance=10mm,
    thick,
    >={Stealth[]},
    auto,
```

I've reorganised the styles slightly because I find it easier to work with a clear hierarchy of styles e.g. a whole bunch of styles need some settings, a subset also need some more and one of that subset needs additional specific settings or whatever. I find this easier to maintain and keep consistent.

```
    basic/.style={draw=black, thick},
    store/.style={ellipse, basic, minimum height=6mm, minimum width=9mm},
    Store/.style={store, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=17mm},
    place/.style={circle, basic,},
    trans/.style={rectangle, basic},
    edgetoken/.style={above=1mm, circle, fill=black, minimum size=2.5mm},
```

We need a new style for the case where we want larger nodes. We achieve this using `every token` and `token distance` to enlarge and spread the tokens a bit.

```
    storage/.style={every token/.append style={minimum size=10pt}, token distance=12.5pt}
  ]
```

We apply the new style, `storage` to all the children of `source`.

```
  \node (source) [Store, label={left:source}] at (0,0) {} [children are tokens, storage] child {node [token] {A}} child {node [token] {B}} child {node [token] {C}};
```

We don't want it for the next node or the edge.

```
  \node (t1) [trans, right=of source] {$t_{1}$} edge [<-] node[edgetoken]{} (source);
```

We apply it to the child here but not the the edge token.

```
  \node (A) [store, right=of t1, label={right:A}] {} [children are tokens] child [storage] {node [token] {A}} edge [<-] node[token,above]{A} (t1);
```

We apply it here to the children of `not_B` but not to the tokens on the edges by use of curly brackets to contain the scope of `storage`.

```
  \node (not_B) [store, below=of A, label={right:not A}] {} [children are tokens] {[storage] child {node [token] {B}} child {node [token] {C}}} edge [<-] node[token,above]{BC} (t1);   % not token A
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: larger, spacier tokens]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.geometric,positioning,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    ->,
    circle,
    inner sep=0mm,
    minimum size=6mm,
    label distance=0mm,
    node distance=10mm,
    thick,
    >={Stealth[]},
    auto,
    basic/.style={draw=black, thick},
    store/.style={ellipse, basic, minimum height=6mm, minimum width=9mm},
    Store/.style={store, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=17mm},
    place/.style={circle, basic,},
    trans/.style={rectangle, basic},
    edgetoken/.style={above=1mm, circle, fill=black, minimum size=2.5mm},
    storage/.style={every token/.append style={minimum size=10pt}, token distance=12.5pt}
  ]

  \node (source) [Store, label={left:source}] at (0,0) {} [children are tokens, storage] child {node [token] {A}} child {node [token] {B}} child {node [token] {C}};

  \node (t1) [trans, right=of source] {$t_{1}$} edge [<-] node[edgetoken]{} (source);

  \node (A) [store, right=of t1, label={right:A}] {} [children are tokens] child [storage] {node [token] {A}} edge [<-] node[token,above]{A} (t1);    % token A

  \node (not_B) [store, below=of A, label={right:not A}] {} [children are tokens] {[storage] child {node [token] {B}} child {node [token] {C}}} edge [<-] node[token,above]{BC} (t1);   % not token A
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```